# Integrating Gefran Linear Potentiometer PY1 with Beaglebone Black

Tags: sensor, adc, analog, circuit-design, beaglebone-black

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEY9Ub.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to connect one Gefran Linear Potentiometer with Beaglebone Black for displacement measurement purpose. The signal conditioner of the Lin. Pot. gives and output of 0-10 V. I am using a simple voltage divider circuit of 8.2K 0.1% resistor and 1K 0.1% resistor. 
Now I can either feed the voltage across 1K resistor to the analog input pin of beaglebone. Otherwise, as I understand, I can connect an external ADC to the output of the 1K resistor and then the ADC can be connected to Beaglebone Black. In the second case, I do not lose out in resolution provided I use a 24bit ADC. Beaglbone Black's internal ADC has a lower resolution.
**Which ADC should I use for this application? Can anybody help me with the circuit diagram for connecting the ADC with beaglebone and the voltage divider circuit?**

[Signal conditioner for Linear Potentiometer](http://www.gefran.com/en/products/85-pcir-for-linear-or-rotary-transducers)
[Gefran Linear Potentiometer PY1 series](http://www.gefran.com/en/us/products/72-py1-touch-version#downloads)

Comment: A schematics would be apreciated, and you don't need 24bit adc, because the voltage reference in gefran (I used them) are not super trooper, they are for industrial use 1%.

Comment: Hi Marko, I have provided a block diagram. Hope this helps. My application is of monitoring load vs distance travel for a pressing application. That is why, for accurate monitoring, higher resolution of ADC is required.

Answer (score 1):

I hve made dozens of force vs. displacement meausurings, so I will explain in short form: The resoultion of the curve doesn't really matter, what really matters is the shape, so don't make yourself a trouble adding an external ADC for the first time. The Gefran potentiometer is very poor, I have rapleced them everywhere, but OK it's up to you. You have two possibilities:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMUFc0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The other one:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdswWD.png)</sup>

You should sample with adc very fast and then implement low pass filter. When force Vs. displacement changes, \$d=\sqrt{v_x+v_y}\$ you store the point in array buffer, since sqrt is time wasting (probably yur MCU can cope with that)is enough to look a threshold difference in both channels.

Comment: Hi Marko, thank you so much for your kind help. BTW, in the second circuit diagram, is the buffering of Vref really necessary? Has it been done with the purpose of impedance matching? Also, what exactly is transil ? (as you mentioned along with the diodes.)

Comment: Ritjeet, buffering the reference is always suggested, and almost always necessary. It is necessary on the BBB. Also, the ADC on the BBB has a strict voltage limit of 1.8 volts, so protecting the input with Zener diodes probably won't be adequate. I will try to post a opamp circuit that I have used on the BBB.

Comment: Oops. Nevermind. Since the top of the pot is driven by Vref, the ADC input can never exceed Vref, and the protection isn't necessary.

Comment: True. Thank you so much for the inputs. As you said, you have already worked with many load vs distance measurements, I wanted to ask one more question. Do you use a similar circuit for feeding load cell/strain gauge output to Beaglebone also? I selected HX711 interface from Sparkfun for the load cell integration purpose with Beaglebone. As the load cell output is in milli volt range, now I feel I can do way with those additional circuits.

Comment: @Ritjeet I used industrial equimpent, no Beagleboard. You need adequate load cell amplifier/ADC. That is more complicated than potentiometer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. BTW, in your first circuit, what is the point of putting the zener diode? Vz of this diode is 3.3 V, so in case anything goes wrong with the signal conditioner, input voltage to the Beaglebone ADC may be well above 1.8 V.

Comment: I didn't know about 1.8V max range. If you are trying to make something serious, then I found a cheap and professional way: https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-68488/l/12-bit-300-ksps-single-supply-fully-isolated-data-acquisition-system-for-10-v-inputs , it's an industrial DAQ 0-10V for very low price, documentation, made from serious company AD. Definitely worth trying. I will check for load cell DAQ.

Comment: That's a great suggestion. I will definitely try this.

Comment: Marko, I am actually developing a prototype now for load vs displacement monitoring. Once the proto is developed successfully, then I plan to develop an industrial grade product for my own machines.

Comment: Hi Marko, is HX711 based load cell amplifier is a good option for this circuit? This is the schematic https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/SparkFun_HX711_Load_Cell_v10.pdf

Comment: @Ritjeet I don't know. Usually the load cell ADC is complicated and expensive. Look: https://wiki.analog.com/resources/eval/user-guides/eval-adicup360/hardware/cn0216, but its slow and the HX711 is even slower.